# Why is Javascript's regex.lastIndex behaving differently for different regex expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let text = "Hamilton is a musical with music, lyrics Book "
let regex = /\s/g

while((result = regex.exec(text)) != null) {
    console.log('idx:' + regex.lastIndex);
}
```

The regex.lastIndex value at each iteration is being incremented and persisted across regex.exec() calls.

Now, if I change the line:

```
let regex = /\s/g
```

to:

```
let regex = /\b/g
```

The loop will never stop and the regex.lastIndex will be always 1.

Why does this work for "\s" (whitespace characters) and not for \b (word boundary)?

The original version of the script is compliant with the documentation of [exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> JavaScript RegExp objects are stateful when they have the global or
>   sticky flags set (e.g. /foo/g or /foo/y). They store a lastIndex from
>   the previous match. Using this internally, exec() can be used to
>   iterate over multiple matches in a string of text

The version after the change seems not to be compliant. Is that a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation which you have read, `lastIndex` starts at 0, and gets changed by `exec`, to the last index of the first match found, after `lastIndex`.

What's the first match? Well, it's the zero-width match at the start of the string. That's a word boundary, isn't it? It's the start of the word `Hamilton`. What's the last index of this match? Still `0`!

So `lastIndex` didn't *really* get changed. In the next iteration of the loop, the same thing happens. The same match is found because `lastIndex` is still 0. Compare this to the situation where you have a non-zero-width match, such as `\s`. In that case, the second iteration of the loop will actually find the second match, because `lastIndex` is *increased* by `exec`.

If you look at the code that `regex101.com` generates, it specifically has mechanisms to avoid this infinite loop:

```js
const regex = /\b/gm;
const str = `Hamilton is a musical with music, lyrics Book `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```